# Object doesn't support property or method 'stop' IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When i click on submit button. I got an error like "Object doesn't support property or method stop " in Internet Explorer but data is successfully added in database.

Here is my code.

```
function SaveComment(subCommentId, trShowresponseId, tdShowresponseId, startDate, endDate) {
//    alert("");
  debugger;
try {
    var response = document.getElementById("TextBoxResponse~" + subCommentId).value;

    if (response === "") {
        alert("Please Enter Response.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //  var isAdvanceComment = 1;
        $("#showloading").show();
        var commentType = 'A';
        var returnReult = dashboards_DiscreteRating.SaveComment(response, subCommentId, commentType, startDate, endDate, 0).value;

        if (returnReult.match("Error")) {
            document.getElementById("spanErrorMessage").innerHTML = returnResponse;

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(tdShowresponseId).innerHTML = returnReult;

        }
        // document.getElementById(tdShowresponseId).innerHTML = dashboards_DiscreteRating.SaveComment(response, subCommentId, commentType, 0).value;
        document.getElementById("trHiddenTextBox~" + subCommentId).className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("trAddSpan~" + subCommentId).className = "show";
        document.getElementById("TextBoxResponse~" + subCommentId).value = "";
        document.getElementById(trShowresponseId).className = "show";
        $("#showloading").hide();
        window.stop();

    }


}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex.description);
}}
```

[image]

Comment: no code , no html nothing! How can anyone help you in resolving the problem!!

Comment: Please provide minimal code where you have encountered this error.

Comment: But it works on other browser.

Comment: I got the answer Internet Explorer does not support ' window.stop()' so we can use 'document.execCommand("Stop")' for IE.

Answer (score 2):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop

> The stop() method is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Also: I don't know what you are trying to achieve by calling `stop()`.

However: you call `window.stop();` as the last line in your file. Since you don't rollback in your `catch`-block or anything, everything before that call (e.g. writing to database) gets executed and not rolled back

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `window.stop()`, return `false` or call `preventDefault` on the event object in the form’s `submit` listener – likely wherever you call `SaveComment`. Something along the lines of:

```
commentForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    // …
    SaveComment(…);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The alert here suggests you might already be passing the return value straight through:

```
alert("Please Enter Response.");
return false;
```

in which case you should be able to do it here too:

```
$("#showloading").hide();
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved this error by using this .

```
function SaveComment(subCommentId, trShowresponseId, tdShowresponseId, startDate, endDate) {
//    alert("");
  debugger;
try {
    var response = document.getElementById("TextBoxResponse~" + subCommentId).value;

    if (response === "") {
        alert("Please Enter Response.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //  var isAdvanceComment = 1;
        $("#showloading").show();
        var commentType = 'A';
        var returnReult = dashboards_DiscreteRating.SaveComment(response, subCommentId, commentType, startDate, endDate, 0).value;

        if (returnReult.match("Error")) {
            document.getElementById("spanErrorMessage").innerHTML = returnResponse;

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(tdShowresponseId).innerHTML = returnReult;

        }
        // document.getElementById(tdShowresponseId).innerHTML = dashboards_DiscreteRating.SaveComment(response, subCommentId, commentType, 0).value;
        document.getElementById("trHiddenTextBox~" + subCommentId).className = "hide";
        document.getElementById("trAddSpan~" + subCommentId).className = "show";
        document.getElementById("TextBoxResponse~" + subCommentId).value = "";
        document.getElementById(trShowresponseId).className = "show";
        $("#showloading").hide();
        if ($.browser.msie) { //************** Here is the answer ************
            document.execCommand('Stop'); //************** Here is the answer ***********
        }
        else {
            window.stop();
        }


    }


}
catch (ex) {

    alert(ex.description);
}}
```

Internet Explorer does not support  **window.stop()** so we can use **document.execCommand("Stop")** for IE.